# Springsecurity AJAX request authorized failed and redirect to login page,

Tags: java, spring-session

In my project i use AuthorizationManager to authorizating my request with database.

```
@Override
public AuthorizationDecision check(Supplier<Authentication> authentication, RequestAuthorizationContext object) {
    String requestUrl = object.getRequest().getRequestURI().replace(".html","");
    LoginUser user = (LoginUser) authentication.get().getPrincipal();
    log.info("Check authorization for " + user.getId() + " @ " + requestUrl);
    if (userAuthorService.CheckMenuAuthorization(user.getId(), requestUrl)) {
        return new AuthorizationDecision(true);
    }
    return new AuthorizationDecision(false);
}
```

But some request i need AccessDeniedHandler to return json string,while i using jquery to send get/post requests.in my configuration:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, AuthorizationManager<RequestAuthorizationContext> authz) throws Exception {
    http.exceptionHandling((handling)->handling
            .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())
    );
    http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/login").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/static/favicon.ico").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/favicon.ico").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/static/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/error").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/profile.html").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
                    .requestMatchers("/**").access(authz)
                    .anyRequest().denyAll()
    );
    http.rememberMe((remember) -> remember
            .key("xxxxxxxxxx")
            .rememberMeCookieName("xxxxxxxxxxx")
            .tokenValiditySeconds(5184000)
    );
    http.formLogin((formlogin) -> formlogin
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/loginchk")
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
    );
    http.userDetailsService(loginUserService);
    return http.build();
}
```

and here is my problem:
while i send get request:api/user/read?uid=10000 [it's not authorized in login]

my AuthorizationManager return a AuthorizationDecision(false);
but i got a redirect to login page but not triggered AccessDeniedHandler,
seems the springsecurity need me to login again to "update" my authorization
how can i do to avoid redirect? or did i missed something in configuration?